# Xamarin forms showing white screen is showing before splash screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, msdn

Im developing an application using Xamarin forms for my android and  iOS application. Currently when the application is being launched , a white screen is shown before my SplashScreen. How can we remove the white screen and shows directly the splash screen ?

`App.xaml.cs`

```
  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SplashScreen());
```

`MainActivity.cs`

```
{
    [Activity(Label = "testApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
    {
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the splash screen has to be implemented per platform. More about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen

Comment: The white screen is native to the platform (Android and iOS) so it can't just be removed. You can set the splash screen color separately on both platforms.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT - so you are saying that there is no way in removing the white screen before splash screen.

Comment: You can replace all navigation with shell and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Android 12 doesn't allow an additional activity to act as a splash screen, so the link above is way out of date. The solution at the following link will enable a splash screen for any Xamarin.Android app. https://github.com/gmck/XamarinBasicSplashScreen.

The following is a link to the official android docs https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: The above GitHub code shows splashScreen for native android , but how can it be done using xamarin forms

Comment: Exactly the same way. Did you even try with your own app? Did you read the comments from the other guy who is using it in his forms app?